# I have been stuck on this for sometime. I am trying to find a value (138 in the below example) and the next 0 after it

Tags: pandas, data-analysis

```
     TimeStamp         Value
2014-12-19 12:41:54     0
2014-12-19 13:10:44     138
2014-12-19 13:12:45     0
2014-12-19 21:03:09     4
2014-12-20 04:53:29     138
2014-12-20 12:43:54     6
2014-12-20 13:12:46     0

Desired Output

    TimeStamp         Value
2014-12-19 13:10:44     138
2014-12-19 13:12:45     0
2014-12-20 04:53:29     138
2014-12-20 13:12:46     0
```

So I tried to entire a pattern as [138,0] and look for it in a column, it works but skips some values where 138 is not directly followed by 0. (As shown in the above example) Is there any way this can be done?

```
pattern = [138,0] 
matched = pd.DataFrame(Data["Value"].rolling(len(pattern)).apply(lambda x: all(np.equal(x, pattern))))
matched = matched.sum(axis = 1).astype(bool)  
idx_matched = np.where(matched)[0]
subset = [range(match-len(pattern)+1, match+1) for match in idx_matched]
result = pd.concat([Data.iloc[subs,:] for subs in subset], axis = 0)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

First filter only `138` or `0` values by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['Value'].isin([138, 0])]
```

And then filter `[138, 0]` pattern with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for equal chained with `&` for bitwise AND with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
m1 = df['Value'].eq(138) & df['Value'].shift(-1).eq(0)
m2 = df['Value'].eq(0) & df['Value'].shift().eq(138)
df = df[m1 | m2]
print (df)
             TimeStamp  Value
1  2014-12-19 13:10:44    138
2  2014-12-19 13:12:45      0
4  2014-12-20 04:53:29    138
6  2014-12-20 13:12:46      0
```

If need testing pattern per dates only use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with grouping by [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
m1 = df['Value'].eq(138) & df.groupby(df['TimeStamp'].dt.date)['Value'].shift(-1).eq(0)
m2 = df['Value'].eq(0) & df.groupby(df['TimeStamp'].dt.date)['Value'].shift().eq(138)
df = df[m1 | m2]
print (df)
            TimeStamp  Value
1 2014-12-19 13:10:44    138
2 2014-12-19 13:12:45      0
4 2014-12-20 04:53:29    138
6 2014-12-20 13:12:46      0
```